# Train Word2Vec on 100+GB of data

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I have more than 100Gb of text data stored on s3 in multiple parquet file. I need to train a Word2Vec model on this. I tried using Spark but it run into memory error for more than 10GB data.

My next option is to train using TensorFlow on EMR. But I am unable to decide what should be right training strategy for such case? One big node or multiple small nodes, what should be size of that node. How tensorflow manage distributed data? Is batch training an option?

Comment: Just a note : in Spark, W2Vec training is not limited by the size of the training dataset (I mean the number of documents or their length). The limiting factor (usually) is the size of the final matrix that has to fit in one node. Its size is `{number of distinct words} *  {dimensions} * {size of float}`. If you fail with OutOfMemory, it probably is because you have too many different words in your training set, and lemmatization and/or thresholding usually helps. Could you expand on the nature of your training dataset ?

Comment: Thanks, there are a lot of distinct words. more than 3M just for english. Actually I need to consider bigram and trigrams also, thus distinct words explodes. I am training on youtube comment data.